# Is it possible to have multiple characters on one Runescape account?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I want to start up an Iron-Man character on Old School Runescape, but I do not want to start up a new account to do so. I already have an OSRS account (that I made a while ago when it came out), but I would like to play Iron-Man or Hardcore Iron-Man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly Runescape does not support this function the best solution would be to make a new account and use it for that purpose.

My one and only recommendation though would be todo *example+**rs2**@gmail.com* for your new account so you can easily keep track of it!

Comment: Dang, I was hoping I wouldn't have to pay another membership to make myself an Iron-Man account with access to members content.